# insert blob with spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, blob, jdbctemplate

I am trying to insert blob in table using jdbctemplate by following code

```
LobHandler handler = new DefaultLobHandler();
int dbresponse = jdbcTemplate.update(DBConstants.INSERT_INVOICE, new Object[]{invoiceBean.getVendorid(),
        new SqlLobValue(invoiceBean.getInvoiceImage(), invoiceBean.getInvoiveImageLength(), handler), invoiceBean.getInvoiceDate()}, 
        Types.INTEGER,Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR);
```

but getting following error

```
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException

.......

    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.SqlLobValue
```

I had made invoiceBean class as Serializable but getting same error.

NOTE: Images with small size are inserted succesfully to database but issue comes with large image size typically greater than 1 MB

Kindly advice !!!

Comment: In your controller you should determine the size in bytes of the file using the getSize method of the multipart object. Thats the value you should return in the getInvoiveImageLength method

Comment: did you make it work ?

Comment: i had temporarily switch to upload image to FileSystem due to time crunch. I will work on your suggestions and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last parameter should be an int array:

```
LobHandler handler = new DefaultLobHandler();
int dbresponse = jdbcTemplate.update(
                       DBConstants.INSERT_INVOICE, 
                       new Object[]{
                               invoiceBean.getVendorid(),
                               new SqlLobValue(invoiceBean.getInvoiceImage(), invoiceBean.getInvoiveImageLength(), handler), 
                               invoiceBean.getInvoiceDate()}, 
                       new int[] {Types.INTEGER, Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR});
```

Comment: Now, getting this error: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (1559540 > 1048576).

Comment: Its a getter method that returns InputStream object. Actually, the flow is i am getting Multipart Object on the controller and setting the inputstream object from multipart to invoicebean class (that contains invoiceImage of type inputstream)

Comment: The problem is that the length of the inputStream is being calculated incorrectly.You need to provide the total length I think you are providing a partial length when calling getInvoiveImageLength

Comment: Check the spring documentation for MultipartFile.getSize() http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getSize--